IAP for Appstore using Unity
I'm having significant issues getting my in-app purchases to work on Apple's App Store. I'm unsure what's going wrong, and the feedback from Apple's reviewer hasn't been very helpful. I'm reaching out here in hopes that someone might be able to offer some guidance.
Playstore
Everything works as expected on Playstore. So we can rule that one out
Catalog Setup

The catalog of the items looks similar to the example above. ID and i put overrides with the same ID. Just to make sure that it does not change for any reason.

In AppStore connect the items looks like following. With corresponding ID:s to the unity catalog. So they match.
Sandbox account
I have created a sandbox account and logged in on set sandbox account on my testing device.
Testing
I have tested to build directly from XCode a debug build to the device with the sandbox account.
Nothing happens of course when i click the button of one of the IAP products.
UnityIAP: Received 0 products and 7 invalid products

When checking the logs. I see that the application is trying to grab products. For some reason all of the products are invalid.
Failed to buy gems
Purchase failed because Purchasing was not initialized correctly

When clicking one of the product buttons. I get a error message as above.

Does the bundle identifier match the one from the app store?
